# g++7 compile error when member function name as errno and cerrno included

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, g++

> main.cc

```
#include <cerrno>

class A { 
public:
    int errno();
};

int A::errno()
{
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

> compile main.cc with g++ report error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/cerrno:42:0,
             from 1.cc:1:
main.cc:8:8: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
int A::errno()
```

But the same code compile successfully by g++6 and below

And the following code compile successfully by g++7

```
#include <cerrno>

class A { 
public:
    int errno()
    {   
        return 0;
    }   
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

So any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`errno` is a macro.
Quoting [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cerrno)

> macro which expands to POSIX-compatible thread-local error number variable

if you add an `#undef errno` in your sources it will compile but somehow defeats the purpose of errno.
You simply should not name a method errno.
To figure out why it works in one case and not in the other you need to expand the `errno` macro and see what was generated.

So here is the output or what the compiler tries to compile:

```
class A {
public:
    int (*__errno_location ())(){return 0;}
};

class A {
public:
    int(*foo()) ();
};
int A::(*__errno_location ())(){return 0;}
```

Comment: how to explain the case 2 get compiled

Comment: If I find some time I will run it through a compiler. But the answer is quite simple. While in the first case the `A::<errno>` will be invalid in the second case the inline macro expansion will yield a valid c++.
As far as I remember `errno` expanded to something like`*__errno_location()`

Comment: fine. I think you're right, I'll rename the method, thanks

Comment: c++ force the errno to be a macro, so if the errno is extern int, it's get compiled